# VR footage is shaky

Tags: streaming, steam-vr, obs, meta-quest-2

I've been streaming+recording my HL:Alyx gameplay to friends, and noticed that the footage that OBS gets from the game directly is very shaky.
Im using Meta-quest 2 headset connected via steamlink to play the game.
Is there a way to fix that?

From my research, it appears like the issue is coming from the fps difference between my VR headset and the actual game. I tried to search for obs plugins that might fix the issue in real time, but there is just one plugin on github that didnt even appear in my obs settings, and from the description it might require computing power I might not have.

If there is no way of fixing that while streaming, maybe there is at least adobe premiere tool that can help with the footage?

Comment: What do you mean by shaky? Is the footage poor or delayed?

Comment: It's literally shaky. Small little movements of the head that are seen  when being completely still. No delay at all.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand. Just to check, you're saying that the game feed that you see moves around, even when you're not moving your head?

Comment: The game itself- not, the footage recorded- yes.